# Elastic Get Data from Multiple Index with All the Data with Priority of 1 Index for updaed Data

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have 2 elastic indexes called **index1** and **index2**. **index2** contains entries where some of the rows from **index1** has been replicated with a single field change.

I want to execute one single query in Elastic from both the index and get all the values out of there in a single result (I can run multiple queries and achieve the desired. But as the Data volume is very high, want to optimize the time if possible).

a) **index2** values that match (by ID, a field) with **index1** will be updated only on the results.

b) Rest of the **index1** data will come as usual on the results.

c) Both the data will come as **combined** in the results.

In short, **index2** will have priority for the results. I have tried many code variations (**script**, **source**, **nested**, **ordering**) of Elastic but failed to achieve the desired output.

Can anyone kindly help with it, please? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to achieve what you need using [field collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html), i.e. by collapsing on the ID field and leveraging `inner_hits` with `sort` by `_index`

```
GET index1,index2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "ID": ["12345", "23456", "34567"]
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "ID",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "most_recent",                  
      "size": 5,                              
      "sort": [ { "_index": "desc" } ]
    }        
  }                
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Even though my ID field was a text field, I have been able to make it work.